# Use Scanner to tokenize a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to tokenize a text file where tokens are defined by "[a-zA-Z]+" 
The following works:

```
Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");

File f = new File(...);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream); e problem is 

String word = null;

while( (word = scanner.findWithinHorizon(WORD, (int)f.length() )) != null ) {
    // process the word
}
```

The problem is that `findWithinHorizon` requires `int` as the horizon while the 
file length is of type `long`.

What is a sensible way tokenize a large file using a Scanner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delimiter that is the negation of the matching pattern:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
while(s.hasNext()) {
    String token = s.next();
    // do something with "token"
}
```